# cannot send data array to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a project created with react, node, and mysql. In the home page there is a form which contain data, email, and file upload. The problem is i want to have multiple file upload. But mysql would not let me do that with varchar (I don't know if my method is wrong).

I tried to use

```
const reqFiles = [];
    const url = "localhost:3001/images/"
    for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
        reqFiles.push((url + req.files[i].filename))   
    }
```

but it returns 2 row, I want all the array images in one column called `Attachments`. I tried not to use push method but it returns localhost:3001/images/undefined. But the image is uploaded to the folder in node. I need some helps. Thanks

**Form.js**

```
const Form = () => {

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  
    const { emailLog, setEmailLog } = useContext(EmailUser);
    const { loginStatus, setLoginStatus } = useContext(LoginStatus);
    const { formData , setFormData} = useContext(FormData);


  return (
    <form method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data' action='http://localhost:3001/registration'>
    <div className='sign-up-container'>
      <input type='email' value={emailLog} name='email' required onChange={(e) => {
        setEmailLog(e.target.value) }} />
      <input type='text' placeholder='Company Name' name="CompanyName" required value={formData.cName}  onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, cName: event.target.value })}/>
      <input type='text' placeholder='Address' name="Address" required value={formData.Address} onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, Address: event.target.value })}  />
      <input type='tel' placeholder='Phone Number' name="Phone" required value={formData.phoneNumber} onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, phoneNumber: event.target.value })}  />
      <input type='text' placeholder='President Director Name' name="PresidentName" required value={formData.presidentName} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, presidentName: event.target.value})} />
      <input type='email' placeholder='Manager Email' name="ManagerEmail" required value={formData.managerEmail} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, managerEmail: event.target.value})}  />
      <input type='tel'  placeholder='Manager Phone' name="ManagerPhone" required value={formData.managerPhone} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, managerPhone: event.target.value})} />
      <input type='email'  placeholder='PIC Email' name="PICEmail" required value={formData.picEmail} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, picEmail: event.target.value})} />
      <input type='tel'  placeholder='PIC Phone' name="PICPhone" required value={formData.picPhone} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, picPhone: event.target.value})} />
      <input type='date'  placeholder='Date' name="EstablishedDate" required value={formData.date} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, date: event.target.value})} />
        <select className='selectBox' name='ChoiceBusiness' required onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({...formData, mainBusiness: event.target.value})} >
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Main Business...</option>
                  <option value="Software License">Software License</option>
                  <option value="IT Services & Consulting">IT Services & Consulting</option>
                  <option value="IT Outsourcing">IT Outsourcing</option>
                  <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                  <option value="General Trading">General Trading</option>
                  <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
        <select className='selectBox' name='EmployeeNumber' required onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({...formData, employeeNumber: event.target.value})} >
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Employee Number...</option>
                <option value="1-50">1-50</option>
                <option value="51-100">51-100</option>
                <option value="101-250">101-250</option>
                <option value="251-500">251-500</option>
                <option value="500+">500+</option>
        </select>
      <input type="number"  placeholder='Number of Customer' name="NumberOfCustomer" required value={formData.numberOfCustomer} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, numberOfCustomer: event.target.value})} />
      <input type="file" name='pdfFiles' multiple required onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, myFile : event.target.value})}  />
          <button type='submit'> SEND ALL</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  )
}


export default Form
```

**FormDefault.js**

```
const FormDefault = () => {

  const [page, setPage ] = useState(0);

  const FormTitles = ["Supplier Data", "Document Required"];

  const { emailLog, setEmailLog } = useContext(EmailUser);
  const { formData , setFormData} = useContext(FormData);

  const [file, setFile] = useState();

  const sendForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/registration" , {
        email : emailLog,
        CompanyName : formData.cName,
        Address : formData.Address,
        Phone : formData.phoneNumber,
        PresidentName : formData.presidentName,
        ManagerEmail : formData.managerEmail,
        ManagerPhone : formData.managerPhone,
        PICEmail : formData.picEmail,
        PICPhone : formData.picPhone,
        EstablishedDate : formData.date,
        ChoiceBusiness : formData.mainBusiness,
        EmployeeNumber : formData.employeeNumber,
        NumberOfCustomer : formData.numberOfCustomer,
        imgsrc : formData.myFile
    }).then((response)=> {
      console.log(response) 
    })
  }
  
  const PageDisplay = () => {
    if ( page == 0 ){
        return <Form  formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />
    } else if ( page == 1) {
        return <FormCheckbox />
    } 
  };

  return (
    <div className='form'>
        <div className='progressbar'>
            <div style={{width : page == 0 ? "50%" : "100%"}}></div>
        </div>
    

        <div className='form container'>
            <div className='header'>
                <h1>{FormTitles[page]}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className='body'>{PageDisplay()}</div>
            <div className='footer'>
                <button 
                disabled={ page == 0}
                onClick={() => {
                    setPage((currPage) => currPage -1 )
                }}>Prev</button>
               
            </div>
        </div>
               
      
                <button 
                disabled={page == FormTitles.length - 1}
                onClick={() => {
                        setPage((currPage) => currPage + 1 )
                    
                }}>Next
                </button>
    </div>

  )
}

export default FormDefault
```

**index.js(backend)**

```
const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "work"
});


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'Images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() +  path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

app.use(
    cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
})
);


app.use(express.json());
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
    session({
    key: "userId",
    secret: "subscribe",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000,
    },
})
);

var upload = multer({storage: storage});


app.post("/registration", upload.array('pdfFiles', 10), (req, res) => {
    const Email = req.body.email;
    const CompanyName = req.body.CompanyName;
    const Address = req.body.Address;
    const PhoneNumber = req.body.Phone;
    const PresidentName = req.body.PresidentName;
    const ManagerEmail = req.body.ManagerEmail;
    const ManagerPhone = req.body.ManagerPhone;
    const PICEmail = req.body.PICEmail;
    const PICPhone = req.body.PICPhone;
    const EstablishedDate = req.body.EstablishedDate;
    const MainBusiness = req.body.ChoiceBusiness;
    const EmployeeNumber = req.body.EmployeeNumber;
    const NumberCustomer = req.body.NumberOfCustomer;
    const SK  = req.body.SK;

    const reqFiles = [];
    const url = "localhost:3001/images/"
    for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
        reqFiles.push((url + req.files[i].filename))
        
    }

    const imgsrc = `localhost:3001/images/${req.files.filename}`
   
    q = "INSERT INTO mahalkita(Email, CompanyName, Address, PhoneNumber, PresidentName, AccountManagerEmail, AccountManagerPhone, PICEmail, PICPhone, EstablishedDate, MainBusiness, EmployeeNumber, NumberOfCustomer, Attachments, SKMenhum) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    db.query(q, [Email, CompanyName, Address, PhoneNumber, PresidentName, ManagerEmail, ManagerPhone, PICEmail, PICPhone, EstablishedDate, MainBusiness, EmployeeNumber, NumberCustomer, reqFiles, SK], (err, result) => {
       console.log(err)
       console.log(result)
        res.send("uploaded")
    })
})
```

Comment: If you want to store multiple files, you should change your table structure. An 'array of files' can't be dumped into a single column like that. Either make a separate table or create 1 column per file.

Answer (score 1):

What is data type you use in mysql database? if you use `varchar` try to using `json` datatype to store array in your db.